# Inserting formula to cell after every nth row and incrementing the number by +1 in the formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, cumulative-sum

I would like to use a formula `=SUM(B2:B3)` in cells A1, A5,A9 and so on but would like to increment the formula like this `=SUM(B5:B6)` etc.

Here is my spreadsheet links.

What I am trying to do is not as simple as I posted originally but the logic should be same.

I have two tabs in a sheet , namely 'Tickers' and 'Stock Details'. In Tickers Tab I have listed all tickers symbols in Column A sequentially.

In other Tab I have formula in Cell B1 '=tickers!A1' which get the ticker symbol from Tab Tickers.

In Cells A2 and B2 I have this formula respectively

```
=index(importhtml("https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/"&$B1&"/summary","table",6),,1)

=index(importhtml("https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/"&$B1&"/summary","table",6),,2)
```

Each ticker table fill approx 24-25 rows and then I want to repeat the process for the all tickers in first tab.

I had also sharing spreadsheet link here.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uyc-KWvg45QLR4l1CvrKAFIMEZFh-dKIyI12t9Hvi5A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Added spreadsheet copy.

Comment: pls update your example spreadsheet and include an example of desired output

Comment: Updated the sheets which shows desired output , hope it make things clear

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(B1:B<>"",,QUERY(IF(B1:B="",,
 MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B))))))>=ROW(
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B))))))*(
 {""; TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT("♦"&ROW(INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTBLANK(
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B))))))), 2)&"♦",,999^99), "♦")))}=TRANSPOSE(
 {""; TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT("♦"&ROW(INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTBLANK(
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B))))))), 2)&"♦",,999^99), "♦")))})), 
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B)))), 0))), ROW(
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&MAX(IF(B1:B="",,ROW(B1:B)))))^0)), "offset 2", 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

if you want dragging formula use:

```
=IF(B1<>"",,SUM(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()+1&":B"&ROW()+2)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

I found that this also worked:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((MOD(ROW(A:A),3)=1)*({B2:B;""}<>""),VLOOKUP(FLOOR(ROW(A:A)-1,3),QUERY({FLOOR(ROW(A:A)-1,3),N(B:B)*(MOD(ROW(B:B)-1,3)>0)},"select Col1,SUM(Col2) group by Col1"),2,0),))
```

[Here is a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IU-M7DosZjDJHWA9CJdqpLPNOJ2_VgKj7Zpgu7WTJFg/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @player0 Am I misunderstanding something?